# How to get Bootstrap button-like checkbox initially checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the following code in the view:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <%= f.label :private, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    <%= f.check_box :private %> Private
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Technically it works, but when the `private` field is initially true (i.e. checked) the button looks as if it was unchecked. Perhaps it is due the fact that check_box helper generates two inputs, one of which is hidden.

Could someone show an example implementation of [Bootstrap checkboxes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) in the Rails view?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that Bootstrap scripts just do not update the state on page load. So I solved it with this JavaScript code snippet:

```
$("[data-toggle='buttons'] .btn").each(function(i, el) {
  var $button = $(el);
  var checked = $button.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked");
  if (checked) {
    $button.addClass("active");
  } else {
    $button.removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent. So sad it is not bootstrap defaults ... I would add on line 3 `$button.find("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']")` since they are concerned as well.

Comment: This works great when I click "Edit" on a record, but if i independently refresh the Edit page, it does not appear that the script runs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working checkbox from one of my projects generated using Simple Form:

```
<%= f.input :cost, label: "Cost to access resource" %>
```

Which generates:

```
<div class="form-group boolean optional archive_resource_cost">
   <input name="archive_resource[cost]" type="hidden" value="0" />
   <label class="boolean optional checkbox" for="archive_resource_cost">
   <input checked="checked" class="boolean optional" id="archive_resource_cost" name="archive_resource[cost]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      Cost to access resource
   </label>
</div>
```

Is your `:private` model attribute definitely `boolean`?

Comment: Yes, `:private` is boolean. I think I just need to put that hidden field out of label, or at least change the order, since the state of the second checkbox input inside the label in checked.